# Handling GCM unregister when Application force closes or internet not available

Tags: java, android, notifications, google-cloud-messaging

I have created an android application which receives an GCM notification where it sends from backend application(PHP) to GCM.

**Scenario:**

1.User A login with Android device and application force closed or internet not available during gcm unregistering(at the time of logout).

2.User B login with the same Android device.

3.So that User B get's all notifications of UserA.

**How to handle this scenario**

Comment: Yes, You can Un-Register with server as per your need.

Comment: If users manually clear the data or app force closed means what will have to do....

Answer (score 1):

While somebody login to your app you can first check if it is already registered on GCM server & if it is all ready registered, than first make a call to unregister from the GCM, after that make a new call for registration to GCM server and then pass your new Reg ID to local server... :) i hope it will help u..

Comment: If users manually clear the data or app force closed means what will have to do

Comment: In force close system doesn't clear data, and If user clears manually so u can get all info including regId from your localserver, and I hope u have stored this regId on your local server